# Customer of my customer is ...?

Tags: business-language

I am designing an online service that serves employees of customer of my customers. End users in this system are employees of customer of my customer.

And my customers are mostly organizations, not individuals.

How to call organization that is customer of my customer?
How to call employees of that organization?

UPDATE:
I also provide an Application Programming Interface for my customers to work with their customers. So, I need to describe end users in the way that my customers (its developers) understand well. Also, there are several types of end users of this software. For instance, another type is members of support team of my customer organization.

Comment: You call them just like you did right now: *end users*.

Comment: Well, I provide an Application Programming Interface for my customers to work with their customers. So, I need to describe end users in the way that my customers (their developers) understand well. 

Also, there are several types of end users of this software. E.g. another type is members of  support team of my customer organization.

Comment: external / internal customer...try a few adjectives.

Comment: They are your third party.

Comment: As the saying goes: "Customer of my customer is my friend".

Answer (score 1):

As you said, I would use **end users** and **end users organization**.

In fact, you don't need to know how many links there is between your organization and the end users organization but only that they are those who will use your design.

Comment: Well, I provide an Application Programming Interface for my customers to work with their customers. So, I need to describe end users in the way that my customers (their developers) understand well. Also, there are several types of end users of this software. E.g. another type is members of support team of my customer organization.

Comment: @DmitryKaigorodov Why **customers** does not fit? (or *support team members*...)

Answer (score 1):

`I need to describe end users in the way that my customers (its developers) understand well.`

If the documentation is written for (and is being read by) those developers, one could say simply "*your* end-users".